# How to map subdomains to Zend Framework modules in htaccess without the browser address bar changing

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I've got a Zend Framework application that has a http://dashboard.domain.tld subdomain, and the rest of the application resides at http://domain.tld. I'd like to keep all the app code in the parent domain however, so I need to redirect the subdomain to the parent domain somehow.

I've got all the dashboard code in a Zend Module and I've set my .htaccess set up in the root subdomain folder like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/dashboard/$1 [NC,NS,L]
```

The redirect is working just fine, except that the redirected URL is showing up in the address bar, rather than the original URL. I need the URL to remain as it was entered by the user.

I've taken a look at [.htaccess redirect without changing address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304492/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-address-bar) and other similar questions but thus far nothing is helping.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Am I right in thinking, that you need to show to a user everything from domain.tld/dashboard/ as dashboard.domain.tld ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The reason is that I need to apply an SSL certificate to the dashboard, which requires it to be on a separate subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [P] flag in your dashboard.domain.tld configuration.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)  http://domain.tld/dashboard/$1   [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well the site has pretty much fallen apart with the whole URL scheme being thrown out, but I think this might be what I was after. Thanks for your help!