# How to redirect subdomains to index.php and keep subdomain url visible in address bar?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site with multiple domains, like `sub1.mydomain.org`, `sub2.mydomain.org`.

Currently I have this htaccess code that redirects all of these subdomains to index.php and passes the subdomain name as a variable:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/index.php?subdomain=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Everything works well, except the URL address is changing to `mydomain.org/index.php?subdomain=(sub accessed)`.

I want to keep the subdomain name being displayed. How can I do that?

My shared host site is structured as

```
/username/public_html/addon-domain/index.php
/username/public_html/addon-domain/subdomains
/username/public_html/addon-domain/subdomains/sub1
/username/public_html/addon-domain/subdomains/sub2...
```

The above htaccess file is in the `subdomains` directory.

Edit: ----- PROBLEM ABOVE SOLVED BUT NEW SITUATION ARRIVED  -------

The problem with my HTACCESS code is that I used an absolute path (http://www.mydomain...), and that will always cause the new url to be shown, regardless of [R] or not. Instead you should use a relative path.
  However, there is still a confusing problem. Here is the new code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ (can't use relative here) [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \.\./index.php?subdomain=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The first cond/rule will check if my site is being accessed from a subdomain, like sub.mydomain.org. If its true, the [L] will stop the second rewriterule to run. The second rewriterule is using a relative path from the HTACCESS file located on the /subdomains/ folder, and all works well if I enter my site from mydomain.org/subdomains/anysub.

The relative path does not work however if the site is entered as anysub.domain.org. It will trigger two erros: "Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." and "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Anyone would happen to know why? Shouldn't the relative path always be related to where the HTACCESS file is?

Edit: Just figured out that mydomain/subdomains/anysub/ works but mydomain/subdomains/anysub (without ending with / ) will again trigger the get var to be shown. Starting to think this is way too complex to ever get an answer on it

Comment: Possible Duplicate [.htaccess redirect without changing address bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304492/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-address-bar)

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear. Exactly where do you want a request for http://sub1.example.com/ to go to?

Comment: Since I'm not using [R], your link is not a duplicate davinder

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `P` flag to the brackets of the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/index.php?subdomain=$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Adding [P] caused the site to return "Request-URI Too Large. The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server." when accessing directly subdomain.domain.org.