# SEO Friendly URLs Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to setup SEO friendly URLs for my websites but can't seem to get them to work.  Here's the code for my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

deny from all
allow from 46.763.65.235

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(link1|link2|link3|link4)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1/ [R=301]

RewriteRule ^(link1|link2|link3|link4)/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/m_$1.php/$2 [L]
```

Basically when going to http://mywebsite.com/link1 it should show the contents of http://mywebsite.com/m_link1.php

However, what's happening right now is that I go to http://mywebsite.com/link1 and it just redirects to http://mywebsite.com/m_link1.php

Could anyone could show be what needs to bed changed or added?

Comment: Could you explain further what you want, because from your description what's happening is exactly what you want to happen: The incoming URL is mapped to `http://mywebsite.com/m_link1.php` in both cases.  I guess you mean the mapped URL is showing in the address bar and you expect a silent redirection ¿Am I right? On the other hand, from your rules it seems link1, link2, etc. are `fixed` strings to be hardcoded in the rule ¿Why? They could be dynamic if they are always in the same position.

Comment: To make it simple, I basically want `http://mywebsite.com/link1` to show `http://mywebsite.com/m_link1.php` - all of my files that I'm using for this redirect start with `m_`.  If there's an easier way to do what I'm trying then that would work as well, I'm not a pro coder by any means so will accept any suggestions/answers.

Comment: @user1850695 - Please do not modify the question to create a new question. Use the "Ask Question" link on the top right corner of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304492/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-address-bar). You are using the R flag which is causing a redirect. Without that flag, it would do an internal redirect (without causing the browser to make another request).

Update: I think the problem was trying to do a redirect to another URL, assuming "mywebsite.com" was a placeholder for your URL. In that case you do actually want the [L] flag so that whichever rule matches is the [L]ast one that will act. This worked fine for me:

(Note: # comments out those lines so they are not doing anything)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#deny from all
#allow from 46.763.65.235

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^(link1|link2|link3|link4)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1/ [R=301]

#one rule for /link1 or /link2 etc
RewriteRule ^(link1|link2|link3|link4)$ m_$1.php [L]
#another rule for /link1/foo or /link2/something-else
RewriteRule ^(link1|link2|link3|link4)/(.*)$ m_$1.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: I just tried changing `[R=301]` to `[L]` as that question implies and it didn't work.

Comment: If you only changed that line, I don't think that would do anything, I think it would just redirect it to itself (changing domains if that is what is happening). Can you update your question with the current htaccess?

Comment: No problem, just updated.

Comment: I don't think you want 2 L rules, because that is now skipping your last rule. Try removing your middle RewriteRule line and I *think* that should do it. Edit - Oh, and remove the L flag from the previous RewriteRule

Comment: Tried that and URLs are still showing up as http://mywebsite.com/m_link1.php so I just updated my questions .htaccess back to how I originally had it.

Comment: Your updated answer worked PERFECT!  Thanks so much for the help Don!

Comment: No problem! Answering .htaccess questions without just plugging it into an actual site is silly so I just whipped up an example.