# Redirect to dynamic image hiding its path in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

In PHP I have a script that receives a GET variable, finds in the database some values and redirects the user to a dynamic (PNG) image.
Here are the example steps:

User calls the address "http://www.example.com/image/50"

The RewriteRule in ".htaccess" file redirects the browser to the script "callImage.php?id=50"

Content of the script "callImage.php":

```
[...]
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];

$a = pickFromDB("a"); // $a = "Hello"
$b = pickFromDB("b"); // $b = "World"

header("Location: dynamicImage.php?a=".$a."&b=".$b); ?>
```

Result: the user is redirected to the script "dynamicImage.php", that gets the two variables through the $_GET array and produces the PNG image.
The only problem is that after these steps, the user will see in its browser's address bar the full address of the "dynamicImage" script:

```
http://example.com/dynamicImage.php?a=Hello&b=World
```

.. while I'd like to **hide** the address of the last script, keeping displayed the original "friendly" address:

```
http://www.example.com/image/50
```

Is it possible to do it?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
I updated the "header()" statement... it was missing the keyword "Location: ..." :D

**UPDATE 2**
I also tried, in the "callImage.php" script the following:

```
[...]

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $url = "http://example.com/dynamicImage.php?a=Hello&b=World";
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($url);
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

... but browser can't display it because "it contains errors". I'm sure that the file format is PNG because in the "dynamicImage.php" script the statement I used to produce the image was "imagepng()".
The strange thing is that if I put the $url full address in the address bar and press ENTER, browser displays the image correctly!! What's going wrong? PHP is kidding me!

**UPDATE 3**

Ok, I noticed that the "UPDATE 2" code works perfectly. It wasn't working before because in my $url there was a blank space, so even if browser accepted URL with spaces, the "imagefrompng()" function didn't, producing an error.

Now the "callImage.php" script generates the image itself and so the in the address bar there is
http://example.com/image/50

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304492/htaccess-redirect-without-changing-address-bar

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution to have the original url present the image instead of redirecting to the url?

Comment: You mean, for the example, "http://example.com/callImage.php?id=50" ?

Comment: Try changing `header("dynamicImage.php?a=".$a."&b=".$b);` with `require_once("dynamicImage.php?a=".$a."&b=".$b);`

Comment: @Nicolás I don't know if it's a duplicate, because if there wasn't the header("Location: ...") statement, the address bar would display "http://example.com/callImage.php?id=50"...

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar for thumbnails on one of my sites. The basic premise is to use htaccess to rewrite the URL, and then the PHP grabs the proper image using curl and sends it to the browser - you need to send the proper content type which in my case is always PNG, but you should be able to detect and send the proper value if you use variable image types.

Tried to update for your page/variable names, forgive any mistakes. This should result in http://example.com/image/50 remaining in the address bar and displaying the correct image based on the dynamic query. Works for remote and local images as long as the server can load the URL.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^image/(\d*)$ /callImage.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**callImage.php**

```
// Do your database calls, etc and create the image URL
$image_url = "http://example.com/dynamicImage.php?a={$a}&b={$b}";

// Use curl to fetch and resend the image
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url);     // Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);   // Short timeout (local)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // Return the output (Default on PHP 5.1.3+)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);   // Fetch the image as binary data

// Fetch the image
$image_string = curl_exec($ch);                // Even though it's binary it's still a "string"

curl_close($ch);                               // Close connection

$image = imagecreatefromstring($image_string); // Create an image object

header("Content-type: image/png");             // Set the content type (or you will get ascii)
imagepng($image);                              // Or imagejpeg(), imagegif(), etc
imagedestroy($image);                          // Free up the memory used by the image
die();                                         // All done
```

Comment: Ehm... I think it's the first time I hear about "CURL". :|
However I tried the code. On the first time, browser couldn't display the image because "it contains errors". On the second time, I deleted the last statement (for producing the image output) and I received the error:
"Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format in <script filename>"
Finally I checked the $image_string and I noticed that there were a LOT of errors because it seems that it can't find the variables passed through GET mode
("Notice: undefined index in... <scriptname>")
pressed ENTER for mistake :D

Comment: `cURL` is a library used to transfer contents from a URL - basically a command line web browser of sorts, and PHP has an implementation you can use. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL and http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Sorry I just pressed ENTER for mistake submitting the comment. Pls take a look also to my last edit of the top post.

Comment: Try writing the contents of `$img` to the `error_log()` to make sure that it is able to load properly - you may be having issues with the server loading images from itself. Make sure that you are able to open remote resources in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Make sure that `dynamicImage.php` is sending the proper headers as well. I haven't used the exact method(s) you are, so hard to say for sure, but without the actual link it's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: Ehm.. I was able to make it working following the "UPDATE 2" code. The only problem is that I didn't notice that in the $url there was a blank space, so that's why it was loaded in the browser BUT wasn't by the imagefrompng() function. Thanks! And sorry for my mistake! :D